# Where's _WIN64 defined in C++/CLI project compiled as x64?

Tags: c++-cli, win64

It seems to be added automagically in every project I create and I compile for x64 but it doesn't even appear in the project's Configuration Properties/(C/C++)/Preprocessor when selecting the x64 configuration.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

_WIN64 is automatically defined by Visual Studio. See the list of [Predefined Macros](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay.aspx).

Comment: Not quite...When I added x64 platform in Configuration Manager all Preprocessor definitions for x64 platform were empty on Project Properties page